# Can't add my own .h file to standard libraries VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use VS 2017 and add my own .h file to standard libraries so I can include it normally in whatever C++ project (I used to copy the .h file to Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include and just put it there).

It worked with VS 2013/2015 but 2017 is not detecting it after putting it there.

I know this is a bad practice but I just want to know why it's not detecting it and how to make it do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"so I can include it normally"_ What do you mean? You want to include that header to any project on your development environment? _"I know this is a bad practice"_ Then why are you insisting to do it?

Comment: I mean I added it, then if I type #include<bits/stdc++.h> VS doesn't detect it......
and I insist because I use it for Codeforces and everyone uses it for simplicity 
and it's fine because the code won't be used for some real life software.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h